# My Acer VN7 laptop don't recognized disk drive on boot, but recognized it after reboot

Tags: boot, windows-10, laptop, ssd, bios

I have Acer VN7-791G-77GZ laptop and Crucial CT512M550SSD1 SSD drive.
My laptop don't recognized disk drive on boot, but recognized it after reboot. Also laptop hangs after wake up from sleep.

So, how it happens:

1. Laptop is turned off.
2. I turn it on and it shows "Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed". No disk drives recognized by BIOS in boot section.
3. If I simply reboot it, it won't recognize disk.
4. If I boot it from Mint liveUSB it will booted.
5. GParted from liveUSB can recognize drives. Drives are mountable.
6. I reboot laptop. Now SSD drive recognizable by BIOS. BIOS can see GRUB and Windows Boot Manager.
7. So after reboot i've boot Windows 10. Windows can work for dozen hours without problems, but laptop hangs if it goes to sleep.

S.M.A.R.T. by CrystalDiskInfo:

```
           Model : Crucial_CT512M550SSD1
        Firmware : MU01
   Serial Number : 14310CD51FE4
       Disk Size : 512,1 GB (8,4/137,4/512,1/512,1)
     Buffer Size : Unknown
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 1000215216
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ACS-2
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 6
   Transfer Mode : SATA/300 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 2444 hours
  Power On Count : 595 count
     Host Writes : 3528 GB
Wear Level Count : 15
     Temperature : 40 C (104 F)
   Health Status : Good (100 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, 48bit LBA, NCQ, TRIM, DevSleep
       APM Level : 00FEh [ON]
       AAM Level : ----

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 __0 000000000000 Raw Read Error Rate
05 100 100 __0 000000000000 Reallocated NAND Blocks
09 100 100 __0 00000000098C Power On Hours
0C 100 100 __0 000000000253 Power Cycle Count
AB 100 100 __0 000000000000 Program Fail Count
AC 100 100 __0 000000000000 Erase Fail Count
AD 100 100 __0 00000000000F Average Block-Erase Count
AE 100 100 __0 000000000053 Unexpected Power Loss Count
B4 __0 __0 __0 000000001133 Unused Reserve NAND Blocks
B7 100 100 __0 000000000005 SATA Interface Downshift
B8 100 100 __0 000000000000 Error Correction Count
BB 100 100 __0 000000000000 Reported Uncorrectable Errors
C2 _60 _49 __0 0033000C0028 Temperature
C4 100 100 __0 000000000010 Reallocation Event Count
C5 100 100 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 100 100 __0 000000000000 Smart Off-line Scan Uncorrectable Error Count
C7 100 100 __0 000000002EF9 Ultra DMA CRC Error Rate
CA 100 100 __0 000000000000 Percent Lifetime Used
CE 100 100 __0 000000000000 Write Error Rate
D2 100 100 __0 000000000000 Successful RAIN Recovery Count
F6 100 100 __0 0001B90B0E33 Total Host Sector Writes
F7 100 100 __0 00000E052693 Host Program Page Count
F8 100 100 __0 0000119E298F Background Program Page Count
```

Comment: Did you try updating your Bios? My own laptop will never recognize my SSD because it doesn't support it, got it working by putting a Windows Boot Manager on the secondary disk, which initializes first and sees my SSD, then the SSD takes over and continues the boot process

Comment: Unfortunately, Installation of latest BIOS (v1.11) doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally erased all partitions.
Now this disk is OK.